# css Image Not Showing on Webpage

Tags: css, image

I have a page: http://www.online-data-backup-info.com/drivehq.html

The header image (1050_250.gif) shows correctly.("Online Data Backup Info")(White text on blue background)

I am testing the same page on a new host. http://www.online-data-backup-info.net/ss100794/drivehq.html

I have modified the ssi references in the second page.

I have asked the forum on the second site without success as far as I am concerned.

Is there a structural reason why the image is not showing on the second page above.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML for each page *is different*, and the HTML for both pages is invalid:

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.online-data-backup-info.com%2Fdrivehq.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

> Result:   42 Errors, 34 warning(s)

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.online-data-backup-info.net%2Fss100794%2Fdrivehq.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

> Result:   15 Errors, 9 warning(s)

Why did you expect that this would work?

You can make it appear on the second page by adding `class="header"` to `<div id="header-link">`.

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered. This is the only forum which actually helped me find the solution. My knowledge is basic. But thanks all the same to everyone. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your designs are different.
In the first example you have top-nav-position and header-link inside the table td element.
Whereas in the second example, those divs are outside the table.
But more importantly - it doesn't appear that you are referencing your background image at all in the second version.

Use something like Firebug in Firefox to see whats going in in the page....and stop using tables for layout - use divs and css.

Comment: +1 for stop using tables for layout.  Firebug for Firefox is great.  You can also use Chrome's Developer Console.

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered. This is the only forum which actually helped me find the solution. My knowledge is basic. But thanks all the same to everyone. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Both pages are different, and have different HTML tags and design.
Are you sure it is the same page? Maybe you uploaded an older version to the new site?

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered. This is the only forum which actually helped me find the solution. My knowledge is basic. But thanks all the same to everyone. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, this has something to do with relocating the entire site to the `ss100794` subdirectory.

Comment: Many thanks to all who answered. This is the only forum which actually helped me find the solution. My knowledge is basic. But thanks all the same to everyone. Problem solved.